# not getting image using Axios in react

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios

my question is about trying to access data from my RESTful API into react website , all data is load but the image from API is not loading . in local data the image link convert like this :

this is the image in local file:
userAvatar: require("../images/avatars/2.jpg")
and it show in browser like this :
*data:image/jpeg;base64,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*

but in api data in browser it show the image link like this:
("./images/avatars/1.jpg")
it not load .
how to solve this problem .
here is more description:

```
// api requestm in react js 
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/questions?pageNo=1&size=2";

    axios({ method: "get", url: `${apiUrl}` }).then(response => {
      let newQuestions = response.data.data;
      this.setState({
        questions: newQuestions
      });
    });
```

this is the response from api:

```
{
    "comments": [
    {6 items},
    {6 items}
    ],
    "_id": "5efc861002489e0e000b0fdc",
    "slug": "question1",
    "title": "how to ask a question",
    "body": "lorem ipsom question body",
    "date": "22/2/2020",
    "status": "1",
    "author": {
    "_id": "5ef883864be2e60e00c9365c",
    "firstName": "Ahmad",
    "lastName": "Ali",
    "userAvatar": "./images/avatars/1.jpg",   // i want to load this userAvatar Image  
    "__v": 0
    },
    "category": {3 items},
    "bookmarked": false,
    "__v": 0
    },
```

firstName , lastName and ... load and show .but the userAvatar image  from api is not work.
how to solve this ?

Comment: I think the path is not the same path ./ vs ../ in this two cases

Comment: It looks a base64 string for the image

Comment: how to solve it and make my API image Link base64 ?

Answer (score 1):

### Change api to send the path

Insted of the API send this `./images/avatars/1.jpg`

it will send this `avatars/1.jpg`

and you can use a util function to call and try to require the image like this:

```
export function getImgSrc(entityImg) {
  let src = '';
  try {
    src = require(`../images/${entityImg}`);
  }
  catch (err) { }
  return src
}
```

the function get you the 'src' for the 'img' tag.

like `const src = getImgSrc('avatars/1.jpg')`